# Show a form according to the user level in C# and SQL

Tags: sql, forms

Im trying to Show a form according to the user level in C# and SQL, i got data table with User_ID,User_Pass and User_Level, i want my code to see if the pass word and user name are correct and show the form according to user level (1 for manager 2 for employee)
Thank you Very much :)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string connection = @"Data Source=Local-PC\HOME;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connection);
        cn.Open();
        string userText = textBox1.Text;
        string passText = textBox2.Text;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ISNULL(User_ID, '') AS User_ID, ISNULL(User_Pass,'') AS User_Pass, User_Level FROM User_Login WHERE User_ID = @User_ID and User_Pass = @User_Pass and User_Level = @User_Level", cn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("User_ID", userText));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("User_pass", passText));


        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        try
        {
            dr.Read();

            if (dr["User_ID"].ToString().Trim() == userText && dr["User_pass"].ToString().Trim() == passText && dr["User_Level"].ToString().Trim() == "1")
            {
                textBox3.Text = dr["User_ID"].ToString();
                this.Hide();
                Form2 form2 = new Form2();
                form2.Show();
                //this.Close();
            }

            if (dr["User_ID"].ToString().Trim() == userText && dr["User_pass"].ToString().Trim() == passText && dr["User_Level"].ToString().Trim() == "2")
            {
                textBox3.Text = dr["User_ID"].ToString();
                this.Hide();
                Form3 form3 = new Form3();
                form2.Show();
                //this.Close();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password");
        }
        dr.Close();
        cn.Close();

    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: It shows no Error and i can't figure out what im doing wrong

Comment: Can you set a break point between both if's, run the program and tell me if it stops at a breakpoint or doesn't get to the breakpoint?

Comment: i did and this is the error i got
error CS0103: The name 'form2' does not exist in the current context

Comment: The second if-statement calls form2.Show, but it isn't created there, put Form2 form2 = new Form2(); above form2.Show();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all:**

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ISNULL(User_ID, '') AS User_ID,
                                        ISNULL(User_Pass,'') AS User_Pass,
                                        User_Level
                                 FROM User_Login
                                 WHERE User_ID = @User_ID
                                   AND User_Pass = @User_Pass
                                   AND User_Level = @User_Level", cn);
```

The query has 3 parameters but you are only providing 2. You must declare the third as:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("User_Level", Int32.Parse(levelText)));
```

OR remove the last filter from your `WHERE` clause

```
//AND User_Level = @User_Level"
```

**Second :**

Why do you check that `dr["User_ID"].ToString().Trim() == userText` and that `dr["User_pass"].ToString().Trim() == passText` while you know for sure that is true. You filtered on that in the SQL query. Your filter on the if should be as follow only:

```
if (dr["User_Level"].ToString().Trim() == "1") //eventually = "2"
```

**Finally :**

I recommend you use the following fixed code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string connection = @"Data Source=Local-PC\HOME;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connection);
        cn.Open();
        string userText = textBox1.Text;
        string passText = textBox2.Text;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ISNULL(User_ID, '') AS User_ID, ISNULL(User_Pass,'') AS User_Pass, User_Level FROM User_Login WHERE User_ID = @User_ID and User_Pass = @User_Pass, cn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("User_ID", userText));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("User_pass", passText));

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        try
        {
            dr.Read();

            if (dr["User_Level"].ToString().Trim() == "1")
            {
                textBox3.Text = dr["User_ID"].ToString();
                this.Hide();
                Form2 form2 = new Form2();
                form2.Show();
                //this.Close();
            }

            if (dr["User_Level"].ToString().Trim() == "2")
            {
                textBox3.Text = dr["User_ID"].ToString();
                this.Hide();
                Form3 form3 = new Form3();
                form3.Show();
                //this.Close();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password");
        }
        dr.Close();
        cn.Close();

    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

According to your comment with the error `The name 'form2' does not exist in the current context`. You need to correct the last if with the following:

```
Form3 form3 = new Form3();
form3.Show(); // instead of form2.Show();
```

Comment: The last error with: The name 'form2' does not exist is not hard to solve, the topic starter created a new instance of Form2 at the first if statement, but didn't create one for the second if statement.

Comment: Thanks!! that worked perfectly!! i also wanna add that the error i got was because i names the object of form 3 as the same name as the object from form2 and this is the correct code to start form3             if (dr["User_Level"].ToString().Trim() == "2")
            {
                textBox3.Text = dr["User_ID"].ToString();
                this.Hide();
                Form3 form3 = new Form3();
                form2.Show();

Comment: Thank you very much Moslem and Mobstaa, that was very helpful !!

Comment: @user2370201 In SO if the answer is helpful you should vote it up and accept it. If a comment is helpful you should voted up as well

Comment: i have accepted it i just some more reputation to vote it up (working on it)